# Error message when trying to run PyAudio in Visual Studio Code (Flatpak)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pypi

*Linux Mint 20.1*

I was about to run a python program in Visual Studio Code (Flatpak), but then I got the following error message: NOTE: You must install tkinter on Linux to use MouseInfo. Run the following: sudo apt-get install python3-tk python3-dev. I ran the former code in my terminal, but I still get the error message.

Please help!

Comment: Google how to install tkinter on Linux

Comment: @unknown -Have you tried to test the same code in a terminal outside of VS Code? Please check whether the python environment used by the current VS Code terminal is the same as the one displayed in the lower left corner of VS Code. ('_python --version_' or '_python -v_')

Comment: @EXODIA I searched it up, and I got a line of code to input in my terminal, which I did, but I still have the same error!

Comment: @JillCheng I have tried the code in my Linux Terminal AND the VS Code terminal as well. Yes the python environment is the same (Python 3.8.8)

Comment: @unknown -It is recommended that you use the command "pip show module_name" to find the location where the module is installed, and then try to remove or delete the module folder, and then reinstall the module to avoid damage or incompatibility of related files.

Comment: @JillCheng used the following commands: pip3 show tkinter3, pip3 show python3, and all of them replied with the same answer: WARNING: Package(s) not found: python3 and tkinter

Comment: @unknown -This means that in the current python environment, the module "tkinter" has not been successfully installed. Please use "pip --version"(or "pip3 --version") to check whether the module installation tool "pip" is available.

Comment: When I use the following commands: "pip --version" & "pip3 --version", it prints the following message: pip 21.0.1 from /home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

Comment: @unknown -It is recommended that you try to use another [python environment in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) or try to reinstall this [python](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

Comment: I have python3.5 installed, and I am using the following environment in VS Code: python.3.8.8, and when I try to switch to python 3.5, it doesn't show up! So maybe I will have to reinstall my Python!

Comment: @unknown -You could download and install python [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying following commands in terminal

```
sudo dnf install python-tk
sudo dnf install python3-tk
sudo dnf install python3.8-tk
```

Then, I checked pip version

```
pip --version
```

> pip 20.2.2 from /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)

```
sudo dnf install python3.9-tk

pip3 install tkinter
```

I was getting same output each time

> No match for argument: python3.x-tk
> Error: Unable to find a match: python3.x-tk

Then, I tried

```
sudo dnf install python3-tkinter
```

In few moment I had successfully got the packages of tkinter. I used `sudo dnf` cause I was using Linux Fedora. If you are using Linux Arch than, try `sudo pacman`. If you using Linux Mint, Kali Linux or something else than, try `sudo apt-get`

So, you should try

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tkinter
```

double check that you have `pip` installed

Comment: I tried all the commands that you listed, instead with, (apt), but when I tried to run: "sudo apt-get install python3-tkinter". It printed the following error message: E: Unable to locate package python3-tkinter. I am on Linux Mint 20.1